# openCL without external kernel file

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I would like to create an OpenCL kernel without giving access to it to the end user.

Therefore, I can't use a regular external `.cl` text file. What are the alternatives, regarding that I would like to avoid creating a huge text string with the kernel?

And yet another question, if I put this code in an hardcoded string, won't it be possible to access that code from some disassembler?

Comment: Do you actually want to prevent anyone from being able to read your kernel source code at all, or do you just want to embed the kernel source into the executable for ease of distribution?

Comment: @jprice This is for closed source software, so I actually want both.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have 2 scenarios:

1. If you are targeting one single device
2. If you are targeting any OpenCL device

---

In the first scenario, there is a possibility to embed the binary data into your executable (using a string). And load it when you run the program.
There would be no reverse engineering possible (unless the already known ones, like assembly), since the program will have compiled code and not the original code you wrote.

The way of doing that would be:

```
uchar binary_dev1[binarySize] = "..."
uchar * binary = &binary_dev1;
program = clCreateProgramWithBinary(context, 1, &device, 
                                    &binarySize, 
                                    (const unsigned char**)&binary,
                                    &binaryStatus,
                                    &errNum);
```

---

The second alternative involves protecting the source code in the kernel by some sort of "mangling".
Since the mangler code is going to be compiled, reverse engineer it could be complicated.

You can do any mangling you can think of that is reversible, and even combine them. Some ideas:

- Compress the code it using a compression format, but hardcode some parameters of the decompresion, to make it less straightforward.

  - LZ4, ZLIB, etc...
- Use an XOR operator on the code. Better if it varies over time, and better if it varies using a non-obvious rule.

  - For example:

    > ```
    > char seq = 0x1A;
    > for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
    >     out[i] = in[i] ^ seq;
    >     seq = ((seq ^ i) * 78965213) >> 4 + ((seq * i) * 56987) << 4;
    > }
    > ```
- Encode it using encoding methods that require a key, and are reversible
- Use a program that protects your program binary towards reverse engineering, like Themida.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I thought that OpenCL would have an alternative for this. I really don't like the idea of having to code with strings, and have the extra workload of compressing it and ofuuscating and so on...

Comment: And I am targetting any OpenCL device!

Comment: OpenCL as far as I know does not support LLVM format, even if some manufacturers use LLVM binaries as intermediate CL code (ARM). So in order to be fully compatible the string has to be stored. Vulkan will probably fix this by storing LLVM code.

Comment: You lost me there. Whats does LLVM has to do whith this? I am using Visual Studio and/or gcc

Comment: LLVM is what SPIR 1.2 and 2.0 use. For the platforms that support it, it is a way to distribute your code in a platform-independent binary fashion. A better solution is SPIR-V for OpenCL 2.1 but it's not shipping yet.

Comment: Note: Even if you mangle the stored source code, there are ways for tools that sit on top of OpenCL.DLL to dump the unmangled code when you call clCompileProgram().

Answer (score 1):

Use SPIR 1.2 for OpenCL 1.2 or SPIR 2.0 for OpenCL 2.0 until SPIR-V for OpenCL 2.1 is available.